# How can I create new git branch based on current that will pick up all local changes with it?

Tags: git

I am working on branch `develop` and have some local changes on it. I want to create branch `new-feature` that will pick up all the local changes from the `develop` branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply

```
git checkout -b new_branch
```

will do. You can then commit the changed files in that branch.

Comment: does it pick up untracked files also ?

Comment: What do you mean with "pick up"? Git doesn't track untracked files. (Does that make sense? :) ) .. However you are free to add them in `new_branch`.

Comment: You are right, doesn't make sense to track untracked files. I only have to add them to the `develop` branch with `git add` before creating new branch.

Comment: No, this doesn't work. You need to add those files, commit in development branch and *then* create the new branch.

Comment: It works as I said. Local modifications were passed over even though they weren't staged. Files I have added/staged with `git add` where also passed over to newly created branch.

Comment: Sure, this does work. I thought you wanted - for whatever reason - commit them in both branches. What is the question then?